# TensorFlow Object Detection installation error tensorflow/models/research/

Tags: tensorflow, installation, object-detection

As the title says I have a problem with installing TensorFlow Object Detection.
My system:

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty
```

and achitecture:

```
uname -i
x86_64
```

These are the steps I took exactly.
First I verified my python installation:
`python -V` Python 2.7.13 
And my pip installation:
`pip -V` pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)

After that I set the url to latest tensorflow version.

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linu/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

And then I installed tensorflow.

```
sudo pip install tensorflow
```

After this I verified the installation:

```
python


import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

And got `Hello, TensorFlow!` as response.

Now comes the trouble...

I tried following this guide:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md

Ran:

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml
sudo pip install jupyter
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

And those commands all executed successfully.

The next step gave me my problems though..
The guide does not say what directory `tensorflow/models/research/` is (if it's created automatically or should be created by the user and in that case where?)
So I googled a bit and found this one: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2253
stating that I should just create it... but doing so made the next command executed from that newly created directory

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

fail with error `object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory`.
I created the directory in `tester@tester-vm:~/Documents$` so the full directory path became `tester@tester-vm:~/Documents/tensorflow/models/research$`.
I'm guessing that I shouldn't create the directory by myself anyway but would love some tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you checked out the models repo (`git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git`), the `tensorflow/models/research/` directory is the `research` directory in this repo. Basically, this directory: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research

Comment: this was exactly what I had missed. The installation instructions never said to clone the git repo but ofc it had to be done... Thx!